# Use session in javascript for show or not a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a question. So I have a div witch contains adsense pub:

```
<div id="addsense-pub">
 .........................
</div>
```

I have a div with game call :

```
<div id="pzGame">
 ...........
</div>
```

Now in javascript I do :

```
if(obj.number_games_adresse % 2 === 0){
    document.getElementById('addsense-pub').setAttribute('class','display-block');
    document.getElementById("pzGame").style.visibility = "hidden";
    sessionStorage.setItem('show_pub_adsense', true);
}
```

In the template with game a have a method witch is call when user tast on the adsense :

```
function showSwf(){
   sessionStorage.setItem('show_pub_adsense', false);
}
```

I added a new script js :

```
var show_pub_adsense = sessionStorage.getItem('show_pub_adsense');
console.log(show_pub_adsense);
if(show_pub_adsense === true) {
    document.getElementById('addsense-pub').setAttribute('class','display-block');
    document.getElementById("pzGame").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

So the ideas is to show the pub if user refresh the page without tast on the adsense. But after refresh the adsense it not shown. What I'm doing wrong? Can you help me please ? Thx in advance

Comment: Please paste all your javascript code.

Comment: *"Now in jquery I do"*. You don't use jQuery at all :)

Answer (score 0):

sessionStorage only stores strings so you need to compare it as a string.

```
var show_pub_adsense = sessionStorage.getItem('show_pub_adsense');
console.log(show_pub_adsense);
if(show_pub_adsense === "true") {
    document.getElementById('addsense-pub').setAttribute('class','display-block');
    document.getElementById("pzGame").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```